# Strange PHP Syntax - String before $variable? What is this?

Tags: php

I came across a block of code in a class like this:

```
...
public function __construct(
    PDO $pdo,
    CommonSqlQueries $csq
) {
...
```

What is the meaning of the string such as `PDO` before the variable `$pdo`? I don't even know what this sort of syntax is called, much less how to research it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [**type hinting**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) (and it was introduced in PHP 5):

> Functions are now able to force parameters to be objects (by
>   specifying the name of the class in the function prototype),
>   interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable (since PHP 5.4).
>   However, if `NULL` is used as the default parameter value, it will be allowed as an argument for any later call.

Failing to satisfy the type hint results in a catchable fatal error. In your case, it'll occur if the constructor function will be called with something other than `PDO` and `CommonSqlQueries` objects as the first and the second param respectively.

Comment: Thats great. I saw this strange new concept in some code I'm using and it left me feeling pretty stupid. :D

Answer (score 2):

This is called type hinting.

> Functions are [since PHP5] able to force parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the function prototype), interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable (since PHP 5.4)."

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php